# Are extension methods not "the Ruby way"?

Tags: ruby, methods, coding-style, refactoring, extension-methods

When working in C#, I found it very convenient to create extension methods. In Ruby, one might look like:

```
class Fixnum
  is_divisible? divisor
    self % divisor == 0
  end
end
```

But I don't see people extending built in types in this way.

The non-extension way would be:

```
def is_divisible? dividend, divisor
  dividend % divisor == 0
end
```

It seems to me that the second way is harder to read (`is_divisible?(i, 5)`) vs. `i.is_divisible? 5`. Or even, `i.is_divisible_by? 5`.

Is there a more eloquent Ruby-esque way to do this sort of thing? Or is the first method the preferred way?

Comment: `is_divisible?` is that something you would actually write, or just an example?  I can't imagine wrapping a single modulo operation in a method...

Comment: It's something I would write.

Comment: ....why?  It's not like that operation will *ever* change, nor is it reducing repetition or the actual amount of code you write.  It seems like a silly thing to wrap in a method.  How about an `is_zero()` method? Anyway, I don't mean to be combative, Just curious.

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh God there actually is one... that is one of the dumbest things I have ever seen..

Comment: @EdS. You wrap it because it is declarative. It is a totally different level of abstraction thinking `a.divides? b` than `b % a == 0`. Also, I really like the `#zero?` method and wish there was also a `#one?` method.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek - `#one?` would be a good method to write.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: Ok, I don't see how that is useful in any way.  Maybe it's just me, but I don't need my code to read like English.  Honestly, I just don't see why anyone would feel the need to abstract away statements like `if i == 0`.

Comment: Because my brain processes them differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is a somewhat trivial example, monkey patches are generally fine. Better to have the method in the class's namespace than floating around in the middle of nowhere.

Just bear in mind that if you're writing a gem or something that you intend other people to use, your monkey patches have a chance of interfering with *their* monkey patches.

For a simple case like this, it's probably better to avoid it just to be safe.